# What is most common way to play sample buffer in windows in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, waveout

I am developing a cross-platform audio editor (C++) and it has platform-specific `AudioDevice` class implementation. This class plays sounds from memory buffer. Primary OS is Linux, but sometimes i give attention to windows port too.

The current windows implementation uses `waveOutOpen()`, `waveOutPrepareHeader()`, `waveOutWrite()` interface and i consider it deprecated (i don't know why exactly). But most important thing is that this interface is still supported and working in Windows 7, and i don't see reasons for Microsoft would kill it.

Anyway, should i move to another interface that kind a better?

Answer (score 0):

The wave functions have been deprecated for several years (mainly since DirectX became supported on the NT platform).  You should use the DirectX (DirectSound and/or DirectShow) API.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416960(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454(v=vs.85).aspx